# How can I safely transfer a small amount of money to Ukraine from the USA?

Tags: international-transfer, paypal, ukraine

I'm interested in buying something from a person who lives in Ukraine, a country which isn't served by PayPal (they can't receive payment).

The price is a couple hundred US dollars - far from small, but not a large amount.

It's a strictly private transaction, not something like eBay or Alibaba.

What is the most practical way of making this transaction in a way that's safe for both of us, and that doesn't require a massive amount of setup? Alternatively, should I just not bother?

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Surprising to hear that ukraine has no paypal. make sure that they actually don't. Sounds like something that could just be made up so that there's a non-refundable transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a money transfer service like [Transferwise](https://transferwise.com/).  Transferwise will transfer 200 USD to a Ukranian bank account for about 5-10 USD. (The main page says $6, but another page says $10.  I suspect they have reduced their fees, and haven't updated the example - bicbw).

Note: This *will* send the money.  There is no possibility to retrieve the money (except through the courts) if you don't get what you paid for (unlike Paypal).  If you need that sort of guarantee, this is not a solution for you.

I have no affiliation with TransferWise other than as a satisfied customer.